# Join to tables and String Compare (large data set)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am very new to SQL and don't really know much about what i'm doing. I'm trying to figure out how to get a list of leads and owners whose corresponding campaign record types are stated as "inter"

So far I have tried joining the two tables and running a string compare I found on a different stack overflow page. Separately they work fine but together everything breaks... I only get the error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual"

```
select a.LeadId, b.OwnerId from
(select * from CampaignMember as a
join
select * from Campaign as b
on b.id = a.CampaignId)
where b.RecordTypeId like "inter%"
```

### Schema:

```
Campaign            CampaignMember
-------------       ----------------
Id                  CampaignId
OwnerId             LeadId
RecordTypeId       ContactId
```

The string compare is also very slow. I am looking at a table of 600M values. Is there a faster alternative?

Is there also a way to get more specific errors in MySQL?

Comment: Can you post what you have been trying?

Comment: @Bleach I have updated my question with the code I tried. Sorry about that

Comment: you have `b.b.OwnerId` - two b's

Comment: @TheUnknown oops. sorry. made that mistake while copying it over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you format your code properly, it will be very easy to see why it's not working.

```
select a.LeadId, b.OwnerId 
from (
    select * 
    from CampaignMember as a
    join select * 
        from Campaign as b on b.id = a.CampaignId
)
where b.RecordTypeId like "inter%"
```

It's not a valid `JOIN` format.  Also the last part, SQL use single quote `'` instead of double quote `"`

Probably what you want is something like this

```
SELECT a.LeadId, b.OwnwerId
FROM CampaignMember a
JOIN Campaign b ON b.id = a.CampaignId
WHERE b.RecordTypeId LIKE 'inter%'
```

Comment: I saw this after writing out my response. Bravo.

Comment: ooo okok I see now. Thanks so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  select CampaignMember.LeadId, Campaign.OwnerId from
    Campaign
    inner join
    CampaignMember
    on CampaignMember.CampaignId= Campaign.id
    where Campaign.RecordTypeId like "inter%"
```

Comment: @SeamoreBJenkins please post results of EXPLAIN from TheUnknown suggestion so we can verify your indexes are helping you.  Along with SHOW INDEX FROM Campaign;  and  SHOW INDEX FROM CampaignMember;   You may need to use single quotes rather than " around your constant in the WHERE.  Also, please post results of  SHOW CREATE TABLE Campaign;  and  SHOW CREATE TABLE CampaignMember; to allow confirmation of SAME data TYPES, where needed.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MySql is generally pretty poor and handling sub-selects, so you should avoid them when possible. Also, your sub-select isn't filtering any rows, so it has to evaluate every row before applying the `LIKE` filter. This is sometimes "intelligently" handled by the query engine, but you should try to minimize reliance on the engine to optimize the query.

Additionally, you really should only return the columns that you care about; `SELECT *` is ok for confirming things, but slows queries down.

Therefore, the query posted by Eric (above) is actually the best choice.